# Query to delete lines from an outdated table based on ids of another table

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have a table that is getting bigger and bigger. It stores path of images of the products that are posted in my website, but  when we delete the products, the system does not delete the images lines from the image table. So I built a list of IDs of products that are currently published in my site, and I would like to build a mysql query that deletes lines where there is no corresponding product published in my site any more, so I tried to use this, but this deletes every line of the table and not just the ones I need to delete, can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
Delete from my_table where product_id not like ( "67" or
"201" or
"329" or
"333" or
"334" or
"335" or
"340" or
"343" or
"347" or
"348" or
"458" )

...
...
...
```

This list has about 2000 entries... I just pasted some of them here. The problem is that this query deletes everything from my table and not just the lines where product_id is not one of the product ids I am listing.. I hope I managed to explain myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with:

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE
  product_id NOT IN ("67", "201", "329", ...)
```

Comment: i am sorry to say that this did not delete anything, what could be the problem?

Comment: @ol30cean0 can you give some sample data? what's in `product_id` column? is it something like 67, 201, 329?

Comment: yes, actually I used the "parent" column now, because I realized that the product id sometimes is 0, and I dont know why. Anyway, Product_id is "int(5)" and parent is "int(4)" type, the parent column is just a number, like 1, 2, 100, 1000, etc... The same query using product_id worked, but it deleted too many lines, because sometimes the product_id is  0, the parent column is updated, but it does not work, weird....

Comment: @ol30cean0 is it an INT column? We could try with a join, but `DELETE FROM my_table WHERE parent NOT IN (1,2,100,...)` should work...

Comment: please see my edits above, anyway, so you are saying to try without quotes?

Comment: I just tried without quotes, and it didnt delete anything.

Comment: @ol30cean0 MySQL will automatically convert a string to a number, so quotes should not make a difference - at least not on this case. But what if you run `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE parent NOT IN (1,2,100,..,)` that should list all rows that have to be deleted, and `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE parent IN (1,2,100,...)` that should show all rows to keep?

Comment: something is wrong, SELECT *...NOT IN return 0 rows, while SELECT * ... IN returns ALL rows... weird, I am checking here... :(

Comment: @ol30cean0 are you sure you don't have any null values in your list? NOT IN could be weird when using null, eg. `NOT IN (1,2,100,...,null)`, I can't think about anyting else....

Comment: my friend, I apologize a lot. Your solution works. thanks for your time, I didnt realize that the parent field was written with a mistake, it is "parenti", with an "i", and there is also a "parent" field, this table is messed up, not my fault..... sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes instead of double and commas in your list of ids instead of `or`

```
Delete from my_table where product_id not in ( '67', '201', '329', ...
```

Comment: well, i am so sorry to say that the query did not delete anything. What could be the problem?